# algorithm to delete node from singly linked list in a given position

Tags: algorithm

```
deleteelement(listc:ptrc, n :integer)
varaiables:  ptr,temp:ptrc
              P:integer
ptr<---listc
p<----0
n<---n-1
temp<---ptr
while(P<n && ptr not Nil)
    temp<-----ptr
    ptr<-----next(ptr)
    p<---p+1
endwhile

if(P !=n) then
    write("n is bigger than the list size")
elseif(n=1)then
    temp<--- listc
    listc<----next(listc)
    release(temp)
endif
 
else
    next(temp)<---next(ptr)
    Release(ptr)
endif
END
```

in case im deleting the head is that algorithm  correct  ?
and does it work if im deleting nth node ,
i have temp pointer and ptr pointer , first im checking if the size of the list is bigger than n
then im searching for the nth node to delete it

Comment: In order to remove the head, the caller will need to see their head reference become adapted or even become null (when the list only had 1 node). There is nothing in your pseudo code that hints that the caller's head reference is adapted. It is programming language dependent, but I understand `listc` to be a local variable, so assigning `next(listc)` to it, only has a local effect.

Comment: ```
ProcedureDeleteHead(listec:ptrc)
Variables:cell:ptrc
Begin
list<----listec
cell<---Next(listec)
Release(cell)
End
```
in the pdf that im reading about algorithm that how it's showing how to delete head of linked list

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: is my algorithm correct ?

Comment: Like I wrote, that is not clear from pseudo code. If you specify with the pseudo code somehow that the list variable is passed by reference, then it looks OK, but most languages do not work that way, so it is ambiguous at least.